# Can Jekyll Data files be selected for two records from frontmatter?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-theme

### Desired Outcome

I'd like to define a list of contributors to an article from data YML files for each person.

#### Frontmatter

```
---
collection: events
format: right-sidebar
layout: events
title: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
contributors: [david-amerland, denver-prophit]
image: fiction-book-essentials.jpg
categories: technical-seo
tags: semantic-web
is_post: True
excerpt: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
---
```

#### Layout

```
{% for item in site.data.contributors[page.contributors] %}{{item|inspect}}{%endfor%}
```

#### Data File

**david-amerland.yml**

```
name: David Amerland
url:  https://g.co/kgs/QpjJVr
```

**denver-prophit.yml**

```
name: Denver Prophit
url: https://g.co/kgs/55pDpp
```

### Problem

I can only select one data record. I need a record hash of more than two.

Comment: Not clear. Why do you need a hash ? Do you want to post-process it and for what purpose ?

Comment: I assumed a hash is more than one record? I’m populating json+ld for two or more contributors from data files like I shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible if a where in filter were  available. It's not the case.

You'll have to loop over each `page.contributors` and grab datas from `site.data.contributors`.

```
{% for contributor in page.contributors %}
  {% assign datas = site.data.contributors[contributor] %}
  Output whatever about current contributor {{ datas.name }}, ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So, `contributors: [david-amerland, denver-prophit]` in page frontmatter is valid?

Comment: Yes, it works if front matter values correspond to existing contributors key.